# PowerBI lookup the same value against two columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to display user names on my chart axis. 
I have a table that uses the same foreign key twice, for example;

```
Users
==========
Id  Name
----------
1   Dave
2   Jane
3   Elliot


Tasks
=========
Id Name   ActionUserId   CheckUserId
1  Job 1  1              2
2  Job 2  2              3 
3  Job 3  1              3
```

There are no foreign keys defined in the database (don't ask!!) these must all be created within PowerBI.

I am not able to pull both relationships as the `UserId` is already active against another table.

I have added a calculated column for one `ActionUserId` using;

```
ActionUsername = CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES(Users[Name]), Tasks
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Users[Id], Tasks[ActionUserId]),
    ALL(Users)
)
```

I have tried to the same again for the `CheckUserId` but I get a cyclic dependency error.

```
CheckUsername = CALCULATE(
    CALCULATE(
        VALUES(Users[Name]), Tasks
    ),
    USERELATIONSHIP(Users[Id], Tasks[CheckUserId]),
    ALL(Users)
)
```

How can I get the username for each respective `UserId` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circular error is because those columns are dependant on each other when you write `ALL(Users)`.

I'd go with a simpler lookup approach in this scenario:

```
ActionUsername = LOOKUPVALUE ( Users[Name], Users[Id], Tasks[ActionUserId] )
CheckUsername  = LOOKUPVALUE ( Users[Name], Users[Id], Tasks[CheckUserId]  )
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to the import users table multiple times as aliases (Action Users, Check Users etc.)

The benefit of this is that you can also filter the 'Action Users' table independently of the 'Check Users' table.